# Sorting a list of objects by another list of objects VB.NET LINQ

Tags: vb.net, linq

So, here's a simplified version of the situation:
I have Gyms in a database:

```
Gym: GymID, Name
GymAmenities: GymID, AmenityID
Amenities: AmenityID
```

So a Gym, can have 0 to many "Amenities".  Along comes a user who prioritizes amenities that are important to him or her:

```
UserPrefAmenities: UserID, AmenityID, Ranking
```

Now when searching for a gym in a zip code, I want the search results to be in order of the user preferred amenities in order of rank...

```
gyms = (From g In db.Gyms Where g.Zip = thisRequest.Zip Order By g.GymAmenitys.Contains(From upa In thisUser.UserPrefAmenitys Order By upa.Rank)).ToList
```

Or something like that...

*note that running the above results in:

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'UserPrefAmenity'. Only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
gyms = (
        From g In db.Gyms 
        Where g.Zip = thisRequest.Zip 
        Order By If((From ga in g.GymAmenitys
                     Join upa In db.UserPrefAmenitys On ga.AmenityID
                                                     Equals upa.AmenityID
                     Where upa.UserID = thisUser.UserID
                     Order By upa.Rank Descending
                     Select CType(upa.Rank, integer?)).FirstOrDefault(), 0)
       ).ToList
```

The idea is that you find a user's highest ranked `UserPrefAmenity` that shares an `AmenityID` of the `Gym`'s amenities. If the user has no matching `UserPrefAmenity` the value 0 is taken as rank.

Comment: Getting "First operand in a binary if expression must be nullable or a reference type.  Also, the "==" is supposed to be "=", right?  for this part: (From ga In g.GymAmenitys Join upa In db.UserPrefAmenitys On ga.AmenityID Equals (upa.AmenityID) Where upa.UserID = thisUser.UserID _
                                        Order By upa.Rank Descending Select upa.Rank).FirstOrDefault

Comment: Ah, the "==" is my C# dialect shining through. As for the exception, what is the type of `Rank`?

Comment: I think I fixed the exception (if `Rank` is an integer).